# Apply $scope ng-click event to hidden element after it is displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click

Please ask me for better explanation. I have built a global search function into the header of my site. I want to display a separate input box for mobile search that uses the same ng-click event but the input isn't displayed when the page loads. I am having trouble getting the hidden input value on the mobile ng-click once it is displayed.

The areas of concentration are the search click function is not finding the correct ng-model when the function is triggered. I think it is because since the hidden elements are not available on load the ng-model="searchQueryStringMobile" isn't applied to the scope somehow.

My question is how do I get ng-model="searchQueryStringMobile" applied in the scope after it has been displayed posthumously or post-click ng-click="flipNav('search')" so that it does not return undefined when you activate the ng-click="loadSearchResults"?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl as header" class="container">
    <div id="jesusSearchTop">
        <input ng-model="searchQueryString" class="jesusSearchInput autoCompSearch" type="search" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
        <select ng-model="searchDDL.item" class="jesusSearchSelect" ng-options="item.name for item in searchDDL track by item.id"></select>
        <div class="jesusSearchHolder">
            <img class="goSearch" ng-model="jesusSearch" ng-click="loadSearchResults('norm')" src="/EMR4/img/gui_icons/searchIcon.png" alt="Search EMR" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="siteControls">
        <div id="siteSearch" class="siteControl" ng-click="flipNav('search')"></div>    
    </div>
    <div ng-switch="dd" class="dropDown">
        <div ng-switch-when="none" style="display:none"></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="search" class="dropMenu listStyle4" id="Search">
            <input ng-model="searchQueryStringMobile" class="jesusSearchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
            <select ng-model="searchDDL.item" class="jesusSearchSelect" ng-options="item.name for item in searchDDL track by item.id"></select>
            <div class="jesusSearchHolder">
                <img class="goSearch" ng-model="jesusSearchMobile" ng-click="loadSearchResults('mob')" src="/EMR4/img/gui_icons/searchIcon.png" alt="Search EMR" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, populateDDL) {
            $http.get(badge.credentials[7].home+'data.JSON')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.header = data.header;
                $scope.searchOptions = new populateDDL('tblWebMenuItems',badge.credentials[1].key).
                then(function(response) {
                    $scope.searchDDL = response.tblWebMenuItems
                    $scope.searchDDL.item = $scope.searchDDL[0];
                });
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data+', '+status+', '+headers+', '+config);
            });
            $scope.flipNav = function(choice){
                if ($scope.dd === choice) {
                    console.log(choice);
                    $scope.dd = "none";
                }else {
                    $scope.dd = choice;
                }
            };
            $scope.loadSearchResults = function(uv) {
                var loader;
                if (uv === "mob") {
                    loader = $scope.searchQueryStringMobile;
                }else if (uv === "norm") {
                    loader = $scope.searchQueryString;
                }
                console.log(uv+' - '+loader);
                if (loader == null || loader < 2) {
                    alert('Please refine your search and continue, Thank you!');
                }else {
                    $location.path("/search/"+$scope.searchDDL.item.name.toLowerCase()+"/");
                    $location.search("type",$scope.searchDDL.item.name.toLowerCase());
                    $location.search("query", loader);
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: can you please remove the unnecesarry code and narrow down your question ? That would help me aswering it correctly.

Comment: I'll try, but most of the controller is pretty relevant and I pulled snippets out at the bottom

Comment: OK, I removed the unnecessary bits

Comment: What element are you asking about? This isn't obvious from your question or code. Can you provide fiddle that illustrates problem?

Comment: class="dropMenu listStyle4" id="Search" is not displayed until after ng-click="flipNav('search')" has been clicked. Once that has been clicked, inside loadSearchResults = function the $scope.searchQueryStringMobile; returns undefined

Comment: so in the `$scope.loadSearchresults()` function inside `if(uv==='mob')` condition , you are getting `$scope.searchQueryStringMobile` as `undefined` , is that what you mean ?

Comment: yes the line console.log(uv+' - '+loader); returns this in the console:" mob - undefined "

Comment: $scope.searchQueryStringMobile; comes back undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tested your code and found that it is because of the `ng-switch`.As `ng-switch` creates its own new scope which is child scope of its parent's, so if you use `ng-model=$parent.searchQueryStringMobile` , then it will work fine or If you use `ng-show` instead of `ng-swtich` ,it will work because `ng-show` doesnt create new child scope, it just sets the markup's `css` property `display` to `none`and `$parent` allows you to access items of parent scope from child scope.In your example, `$scope.searchQueryStringMobile` is in the parent scope of `ng-switch`'s scope. Here is the working plunk [click](http://plnkr.co/edit/K3A7krOUR1jOe4iPVQBx)

you can change your `ng-switch` markup to this

```
<div ng-switch="dd" class="dropDown" >
    <div ng-switch-when="none" style="display:none"></div>
    <div  ng-switch-when="search" class="dropMenu listStyle4" id="Search">
        <input ng-model="$parent.searchQueryStringMobile" class="jesusSearchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
        <select ng-model="searchDDL.item" class="jesusSearchSelect" ng-options="item.name for item in searchDDL track by item.id"></select>
        <div class="jesusSearchHolder">
            <img class="goSearch" ng-model="jesusSearchMobile" ng-click="loadSearchResults('mob')" src="/EMR4/img/gui_icons/searchIcon.png" alt="Search EMR" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `ng-model` for the `input` element in the above code.

Comment: I ran into this before because based on authentication I need the elements removed from the DOM completely. Essentially if you are not the right user level I need the code to not be printed in the html at all. Does this make sense?

Comment: if that's the requirement then you can compile the dynamic code using $compile and then append it to the DOM node .

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth  i have updated my answer , check the plunker now .

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth , if the answer solved your query then you can accept it .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite simple one. ng-switch just like ng-if creates new scope, so when you are using ng-model, yu are assign property to this new scope and not the scope used by your controller.

Solution would be to use controller as syntax or use property of some object created on scope. To illustrate this I create example for you.

As you can see {{a}} does not work outside new scope, but {{x.b}} works just fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="x = {}; show = 'first'">
  <button type="button" ng-click="show = 'first'">show first</button><br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="show = 'second'">show second</button><br>
  a = {{a}}<br>
  x.b = {{x.b}}
  <div ng-switch="show">
    <div ng-switch-when="first">
      <input type="text" ng-model="a">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="second">
      <input type="text" ng-model="x.b">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would I go about getting the <input type="text" ng-model="x.b"> value into the loadSearchResults function?

Comment: It is working, just click show first or second and try typing something in input.

Comment: I tried that too but it looks like I will have to pass it in from the client side like this ng-click="loadSearchResults('mob',searchQueryStringMobile)"

Comment: It feels dirty doing it that way though. agree?

Comment: That way it is recommended to always use controllerAs syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112809/discussion-between-erik-grosskurth-and-sielakos).